How to distribute pandas dataframe rows unevenly across timestamps based on value of the column
E.g. DF which contains number of executions across timestamps.
             DateTime           Execution
0 2023-04-03 07:00:00                   11
1 2023-04-03 11:00:00                   1
2 2023-04-03 12:00:00                   1
3 2023-04-03 14:00:00                   3
4 2023-04-03 18:00:00                   1

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5080 entries, 0 to 5079

Below is the output I'm trying to achieve
             DateTime           Execution
0 2023-04-03 07:00:00                   4
1 2023-04-03 08:00:00                   4
2 2023-04-03 09:00:00                   3
3 2023-04-03 11:00:00                   1
4 2023-04-03 12:00:00                   1
5 2023-04-03 14:00:00                   3
6 2023-04-03 18:00:00                   1

Only if the execution is more than 4, it should be distributed to the next hours. Maximum for any hour is 4.
Thanks again for quick help.
How to distribute pandas dataframe rows evenly across timestamps based on value of the column
This helps with Evenly distribution, I'm looking at uneven distribution.

With asfreq/clip :
N, C = 4, "Execution"

asfreq = df.set_index("DateTime").asfreq("h")

out = (
    (gby:=asfreq.groupby(asfreq[C].notna().cumsum()))[C]
    .transform("first")
    .sub(gby.cumcount() * N)
    .clip(upper=N)
    .loc[lambda s: s.gt(0)]
    .reset_index(name=C)
    .convert_dtypes()
)

Output :
             DateTime  Execution
0 2023-04-03 07:00:00          4
1 2023-04-03 08:00:00          4
2 2023-04-03 09:00:00          3
3 2023-04-03 11:00:00          1
4 2023-04-03 12:00:00          1
5 2023-04-03 14:00:00          3
6 2023-04-03 18:00:00          1


Very nice one :)

In a moz'way, TBH ;)

Thank you! In case I want to generalize the solution. i.e. include a factor column. And create additional timestamps based on it. For example for factor 11, create 11 rows and, for factor 4 create 4. Can you suggest how this is possible.
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
11

That would be your third question on a similar topic. I feel like you need to take a step back and think about what you're really trying to achieve. Then, you can open a new question.

Closer to jezrael's solution from the link above:
import pandas as pd
import datetime

values = [11, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
datetimes = [
    datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=i * 3)
    for i in range(len(values))
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "DateTime": datetimes,
        "Execution": values,
    }
)


boundary = 4
div, mod = df.Execution.divmod(boundary)
num_repeat = div * (mod > 0)

new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(num_repeat)].assign(
    Execution=lambda x: ((x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1) < div[x.index]).apply(
        lambda y: boundary if y else mod[x.index].drop_duplicates()[0]
    ),
    DateTime=lambda x: x["DateTime"]
    + pd.to_timedelta(x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1, unit="h"),
)

df_modified = df.copy()
df_modified.loc[df_modified.Execution > 4, "Execution"] = 4

res = pd.concat([df_modified, new]).sort_values("DateTime").reset_index(drop=True)   

